# IE Developer Toolbar turning inspected elements black

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, retina-display, parallels

I am running Internet Explorer 10 under Windows 8 on Parallels on a Retina Mac Book Pro 15" (just thought it might be useful to give all the details).

When I run the *F12 Developer Tools* and inspect an element on click, the element turns completely black, making it impossible to see what's going on when I change a style rule, for example.

I tried the Google Chrome developer tools and they work fine. Is this a known bug, or a *feature*? Because if it is a feature it is an annoying one!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not the normal behavior of Internet Explorer 10, or its Inspect Element feature. I suspect this is related to your setup, and possibly a lack of memory. I've found issues with re-drawing portions of the page as well in low-memory environments, at times similar to what you're seeing now. If you can, try to boost the amount of memory allocated to the virtual OS and see if this resolves the issue.

Here is a screenshot of my setup:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the delay in the reply, I have been without connection for a while. I followed your advice and exaggerated a bit: I allocated **4GB of RAM, 2 CPU and 1GB of video card memory** to the Virtual Machine running Windows 8, but still the same problem applies. Any other step I could follow to troubleshoot?

Comment: @CoolingFan I have allocated 4gb of RAM also, 1 CPU, and 256mb of video card memory without being able to replicate your issue. The other other difference. Have you tried another VM to see if this issue persists?

Answer (score 0):

I've been fuming over this issue all day, installing different VMs from modern.ie but they were all affected.

Here's the fix: in your VM's video settings, select DirectX 9.